# Add a delete Button to each Item in QListView

Tags: qt, qlistview

Is it somehow possible to add to each Item in a QListview a Button which is deleting the Object onClick? As shown in the following Picture:

[image: Item witch delete Button]

EDIT: As I'm new in QT it would be nice to have some example, to understand it better. And as it seems there are three different Ways? What will be the best? Do use a QAbstractItemView?

Comment: How about using delegates? (`QStyledItemDelegate`)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You'll need to use:

```
QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget ( const QModelIndex & index, QWidget * widget )
```

QListView inherits QAbstractItemView and when you're trying to customize list/tree views that's usually the place to look. Be careful though, without a delegate this doesn't scale very well. Check out this thread: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26916-inserting-custom-Widget-to-listview

Comment: Inserting widgets to views are not recommended by Qt docs for interacting with user.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go for a generic approach that can work on variety of containers, including the underlying model of your list view.

Each item in the list has a `requestRemoval(Item*)` signal and a `removeMe()` slot, connect the X button to the `removeMe()` slot in each item constructor, in `removeMe()` you emit the `requestRemoval(this)` signal, which is connected to a `removeHandler(Item*)` slot in your "parent" object upon creation of that item, which receives the pointer of the item which has requests deletion, and removes it from the underlying container being used.

Basically, pressing the remove button causes that particular item to send a pointer of itself to the parent's remove handler which removes that entry.

EDIT: Note that this is a generic approach, as noted in the comments below it can be applied without signals and slots as well, and even though it will work it is not the most efficient solution in your particular case.

Comment: It is bad idea to interhit QObjects for items. There may be a lot of them, and mass connections may be slow / eat a lot of memory.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov - this is true, connections themselves are not that problematic, but `QObject` itself is relatively huge. BUT his example doesn't really imply thousands, much less millions of objects. In which case using `QObject` or even `QWidget` derived objects is acceptable.

Comment: Also, the same pattern can be used without `QObejct` / signals and slots easily, just add a "parent" pointer to each item and initialize it in the constructor, and then simply call `parent->remove(this)`. Total cost - 1 pointer...