# Signal/Slot while model inserts and removes rows in QTableView dynamically

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qt-signals

I am inserting a `QPushButton` in the last column of a `QTableview`. With that button I am deleting that particular row using button release signal and slot `handlebutton(int)`.

cpp code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSortFilterProxyModel *model = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    model = pCApp->guiClient()->getConnectionManagement()->getProxyModel();
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    connect(pCApp, SIGNAL(CloseOpenWindowsRequested()), SLOT(close()));
    connect(ui->tableView->model(), SIGNAL(rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(onRowsNumberChanged()));
    connect(ui->tableView->model(), SIGNAL(rowsRemoved(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(onRowsNumberChanged()));
    ui->tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
    QPushButton *button;
    QSignalMapper *mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    QObject::connect(mapper, SIGNAL (mapped(int)), this, SLOT (handleButton(int)));
    for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); i++)
    {
        button = new QPushButton;
        button->setText("Disconnect " + QString::number(i));
        button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { color: #E5E5E5; }");
        ui->tableView->setIndexWidget(model->index(i,2, QModelIndex()), button);
        QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(released()), mapper, SLOT(map()));
        connect(ui->tableView->model(), SIGNAL(rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(onRowsNumberChanged()));
        connect(ui->tableView->model(), SIGNAL(rowsRemoved(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(onRowsNumberChanged()));
        mapper->setMapping(button, i);
    }
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::handleButton(int row)
{
    this->ui->tableView->model()->removeRow(row);
}

void MainWindow::onRowsNumberChanged()
{
    QSortFilterProxyModel *model = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    model = pCApp->guiClient()->getConnectionManagement()->getProxyModel();
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    ui->tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
    QPushButton *button;
    QSignalMapper *mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    QObject::connect(mapper, SIGNAL (mapped(int)), this, SLOT (handleButton(int)));
    for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); i++)
    {
        button = new QPushButton;
        button->setText("Disconnect " + QString::number(i));
        button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { color: #E5E5E5; }");
        ui->tableView->setIndexWidget(model->index(i,2, QModelIndex()), button);
        QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(released()), mapper, SLOT(map()));
        mapper->setMapping(button, i);
    }

}
```

hpp code:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_HPP
#define MAINWINDOW_HPP

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void onLanguageChanged();
    void handleButton(int row);
    void onRowsNumberChanged();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_HPP
```

In normal case, the code is functioning correctly. But, when new rows are inserted and/or old rows are removed, the buttons doesn't appear in the last column as desired. I tried to use the signals -

```
connect(ui->tvServStat->model(), SIGNAL(rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(onRowsNumberChanged()));

connect(ui->tvServStat->model(), SIGNAL(rowsRemoved(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(onRowsNumberChanged()));
```

Slots for both, I am keeping same as `onRowsNumberChanged()`, in which I am again trying to insert buttons in the last column. My thinking is that might be the row count is getting changed, so I am re-implementing same logic. But, it doesn't work.

Can anyone help in correcting my logic or another logic to achieve this functionality. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn) for that column. This way, the view handles creation / deletion of rows automatically. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933326/add-a-delete-button-to-each-item-in-qlistview)

---

There are also some other problems with your code:

1. You connect `rowsInserted`/`rowsRemoved` multiple times
2. In your code, you create multiple Signal Mappers for mapping the same kind of connections. This is not its intendend use
3. Duplication of the `onRowsNumberChanged` loop

Comment: I was using the delegate before, but it generates the standard style button which needs to be styled. I tried for two days, but couldn't fit the style. With this approach, I able to achieve maximum of the functionality excluding handling of automatic creation/deletion of rows. Can you help me modify this approach. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Also multiple entries is just because I am trying to figure out the correct position. Also, if you can help.

Comment: As stated in the linked question (and followup links to qtcenter), using widgets doesn't scale well. You should really use a delegate. I suggest you post a new question with your delegate approach

Comment: Already done that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812500/adding-custom-style-to-button-added-in-qtableview/45814839?noredirect=1#comment78657522_45814839

Comment: I see... maybe you can try the approach in [this post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26916-inserting-custom-Widget-to-listview?p=155774#post155774) and just style the button?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem using Widgets, you can use the following approach. It uses Qt 5's new connect syntax and C++ lambdas, and thus can eliminate the need for a signal mapper:

```
#include "form.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("add row");
    m_tree = new QTreeView(this);
    QBoxLayout *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    l->addWidget(m_tree, 1);
    l->addWidget(b);

    QStandardItemModel *m = new QStandardItemModel(0, 3, this);
    m_tree->setModel(m);

    connect(b, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Form::addRow);
    connect(m, SIGNAL(rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(addItemButtons()));
    connect(m, SIGNAL(rowsRemoved(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(addItemButtons()));
}

Form::~Form()
{
}

void Form::addRow()
{
    m_tree->model()->insertRow(m_tree->model()->rowCount());
}

void Form::addItemButtons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_tree->model()->rowCount(); ++i) {
        auto idx = m_tree->model()->index(i, 2);
        QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("X");
        b->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: #E5E5E5;}");
        m_tree->setIndexWidget(idx, b);
        connect(b, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){
            m_tree->model()->removeRow(i);
        });
    }
}
```